# How to access the mp3 files from the phone's internal memory using android code?

Tags: android, mp3, internal

How to access the mp3 files from the phone's internal memory using android code?

I am not able to access the mp3 files which are stored in internal storage using:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Can anyone provide solution to my question please?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You look on the right way. Only that you use external memory.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); from this statement am i able to access the mp3 files of phone memory (Internal Memory)?

Comment: problem is i want to get the mp3 files from the internal phone memory only but i am not able to get it.

Comment: `i am not able to get it` is not a description of your probldem. It will nof help you. You are not serious.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to access audio files.

```
void pickAudio() {

    Intent documentIntent;

    documentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    documentIntent.setType("audio/*");

    startActivityForResult(documentIntent, PICK_DOCUMENTS);
}

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {

            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
                return;

            switch (requestCode) {

                case PICK_DOCUMENTS:

                    Uri documentUri = data.getData();

                    break;

            }

}
```